# Android timepicker java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error

Tags: java, android

I have a timepicker wherein  
if hour is 0 it should display as with interval of 5 
["05", "10", "15" -> until "55"] 
and if hour is NOT 0 
["0", "05", -> "55"]

i'll post some of the codes here

```
tp.setHour(0);
tp.setIs24HourView(true);
setMinuteIntervalWithOutZero(timepicker);
tp.setOnTimeChangedListener(mChangeTimeListener);
//set default time on load to 5 minutes
tp.setMinute(1);
```

onTimeChanged

```
private TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener mChangeTimeListener = new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener() {
        public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker tp, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
            hour = selectedHour;
            minute = selectedMinute;

            try{
                if ( hour != 0 ){
                    setMinuteInterval(tp);
                } else {
                    setMinuteIntervalWithOutZero(tp);
                }
            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    };
```

setting Interval (5) and it will display 0-55, if hour is 1-23

```
private void setMinuteInterval(TimePicker tp) {
        try {
            minutePicker = (NumberPicker) tp.findViewById(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("minute", "id", "android"));
            minutePicker.setMinValue(0);
            minutePicker.setMaxValue((60 / INTERVAL));
            List<String> displayedValues = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 60; i += INTERVAL) {
                displayedValues.add(String.format("%02d", i));
            }
            minutePicker.setDisplayedValues(displayedValues.toArray(new String[0]));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

setting interval (5) and will only display 5 - 55 if hour is 0

```
 private void setMinuteIntervalWithOutZero(TimePicker timePicker) {
        try {
            minutePicker = (NumberPicker) timePicker.findViewById(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("minute", "id", "android"));
            minutePicker.setMinValue(1);
            minutePicker.setMaxValue((60 / INTERVAL) - 1);
            List<String> displayedValues = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 5; i < 60; i += INTERVAL) {
                displayedValues.add(String.format("%02d", i));
            }
            minutePicker.setDisplayedValues(displayedValues.toArray(new String[0]));

} catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

if I swipe down the minute until the hour will display as 23(Hour is 0), it will crash and the error will be **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**

could you help me ??

Comment: On what line do you get the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`?

Comment: @DavidWasser it has no line in where I got the error. It only displayed "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=11; index=11" above.


maybe because of this ? 
the setMinuteIntervalWithOutZero has a length of  11 (displayedValues)
while setMinuteInterval has a length of 12 (displayedValues). where in if i swipe down the minute until it will switch to 55 minutes (expected is 23:55) while the hour is 0

Comment: There must be a stack trace that shows where the error occurs. You might be filtering the logcat and missing something important

Comment: @DavidWasser i've catch on Log "D/ERROR:: setMinuteInterval java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=11; index=11"

Answer (score -1):

In `setMinuteInterval()` you have this:

```
minutePicker.setMaxValue((60 / INTERVAL));
```

but you need this:

```
minutePicker.setMaxValue((60 / INTERVAL) - 1);
```

because the values (min to max) need to be 0 to 11 (not 0 to 12)

The crash occurs when you call `setDisplayedValues()` because you aren't passing enough display values to cover the range min to max. The [documentation for `setDisplayedValues()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker?hl=en#setDisplayedValues(java.lang.String%5B%5D)) says:

> The displayed values. Note: The length of the displayed values array
> must be equal to the range of selectable numbers which is equal to
> getMaxValue() - getMinValue() + 1.